# How to list all dependency problems?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies, synaptic

Like being able to [filter broken packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto#How_to_fix_broken_packages) in synaptic, is there a way to list (CLI or GUI) all dependency problems?

Or would dependency issues show up as broken?

I'm confused because each time I install either `libgd2-noxpm` or `libgd2-xpm`

I'm getting the same error, with the packages reversed, of course:

```
dpkg: libgd2-noxpm: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 graphviz depends on libgd2-noxpm (>= 2.0.36~rc1~dfsg) | libgd2-xpm (>= 2.0.36~rc1~dfsg); however:
  Package libgd2-noxpm is to be removed.
  Package libgd2-xpm is not installed.
 libgraphviz4 depends on libgd2-noxpm (>= 2.0.36~rc1~dfsg) | libgd2-xpm (>= 2.0.36~rc1~dfsg); however:
  Package libgd2-noxpm is to be removed.
  Package libgd2-xpm is not installed.
 libm17n-0 depends on libgd2-noxpm (>= 2.0.36~rc1~dfsg) | libgd2-xpm (>= 2.0.36~rc1~dfsg); however:
  Package libgd2-noxpm is to be removed.
  Package libgd2-xpm is not installed.
 webalizer depends on libgd2-noxpm (>= 2.0.36~rc1~dfsg) | libgd2-xpm (>= 2.0.36~rc1~dfsg); however:
  Package libgd2-noxpm is to be removed.
  Package libgd2-xpm is not installed.
```

for example when I try to install `libgd2-xpm` so it makes sense it would complain because it's not installed until after the errors, but I just want to be able to list all dependency issues to make sure. Any ideas? Or anyone know if dependency issues would in fact show up as broken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo apt-get check` is your friend. :)

From the man page:

```
check
```

*check is a diagnostic tool; it updates the package cache and checks for broken      dependencies*

For finer checks (half-configured, etc.) you can try `sudo dpkg -C` instead:

`-C, --audit`
*Searches for packages that have been installed only partially on  your system. `dpkg` will suggest what to do with them to get them working.*